# Cannot find WordPress pages on NotePad++

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, web, notepad++

I am implementing multiple pages on a website. I am using FTP with Notepad++ to edit pages and I am using WordPress. I have multiple pages show on the Wordpress/Version Press,which I can edit through WordPress. But I cannot find those pages on NotePad++. I can only find multiple index.php, index.html pages. Those pages work fine, but I cannot find other pages like an about.php, login.php page etc.

Do I need to manually add those pages to NotePad++ or do I need to change the setting between WordPress and NotePad++?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress (like most CMSs) stores page content in the mySQL database, not as PHP/HTML/etc.  Therefore you cannot modify page content via FTP.  If you need to code things that the CMS will not allow, you have two options:

1- Install a snippet or code editor plugin.  These save your script in a Basecode format so that WordPress doesn't try to mess with it.  This is the recommended method for minor issues such as injecting a few lines of PHP into a page.

2- Create a custom Plugin.  These can be modified via FTP because they are saved as files in your plugins folder, not in your database.  These are best if you have a specific application you need to write for your site.

3- Create a Child Theme.  This is similar to custom plugins, but it is better if you need to change theme functionality on a global scope.  Recommended making major alterations to your theme's header/footer/etc.